# Event to catch Application.ExitThread

Tags: c#, winforms

Title pretty much says it all. I use Application.ExitThread and want to catch when it is being called with an event, but I heard that all the closing, closed, formclosed, formclosing events "block" exit thread. I also tried them myself. What can I do?

Comment: You "heard" that the closing, closed, formclosed, formclosing events "block" exit thread? Who did you hear that from? Did you test it?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned, I tested it. "Blocking" is the term they used.

Comment: Can you remember who "they" were?

Comment: At https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d99e7abf-ffb8-4492-bff0-245e7033b1f1/applicationexit-versus-applicationexitthread?forum=winforms

Comment: That thread seems to suggest that ExitThread will not fire off the aforementioned events. This may be interpreted as the opposite of blocking by some, which is a likely source of confusion here.

Comment: @JonathonChase I think he's using it on the main thread to exit the application, but I'm not going to bother trying to find out. Life is too short to fight people like that for every tiny piece of information.

Comment: Yes what I mean is that ExitThread will not fire these events and I want an event that will be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just handle Application.ThreadExit Event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have 2 forms and it Works in a different way than I expected. I run the application, than move to the next form with Application.ExitThread on the current form and then Application.Run to open the second one, than I close the second form with the X. What it does is it notifies me twice (I put MessageBox.Show inside the function that is called by the event). If I don't go to the second form but close the first one with the X it notifies me once, what lead me to believe it counted that move between the forms, but still only notified me when the whole application is closed. How can I fix this?

Comment: When I said it is notifying me twice and once I forgot to say it happens only when the whole application is closed which is the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ExitThread()` the code remaining will still be executed. So if you fire an event it would probably be executed before the thread exit.

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ExitThread();

    this.MyEvent+= (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This will be executed");
    };

    Console.WriteLine("This line is also executed");
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you're saying.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. You're basically creating your own event, but how does it know when to fire this event?

Comment: @Soogbad you said you want to fire the event when Application.ExitThread is being called

Comment: No, what I meant is I want the event to be fired when Application.ExitThread is being called

Comment: Or is that also what you meant